# How to convert osm way xml to openlayers feature?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, format

I am displaying the osm data through a popup with openlayers. For now i am using the overpass api to get data.

But my app needs to reflect the rapidly changing data i.e. one changes the data then uses my app, then they need to see the new data.

The one minute lag of overpass api is not acceptable, so i have decided to use the

1. skel mode of overpass api to display feature,
2. Get id and geometry
3. query the feature from osm database

this way i can limit the data usage also.

Now i have an Openlayers Vector Layer using OpenLayers.Format.OSM. i can add features to it.

i need to convert an xml data in [this format](http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/191189605)
to an OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.

Comment: You can use json with mapquest example: http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?format=json&osm_type=W&osm_id=191189605

Comment: i don't think osm provides response in json format. And any other service cannot provide updated data as fast as i need. (every other service will be at least 1 min late, which is not acceptable).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a format to read new features, parse it and add it to the layer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a vector layer with [OpenLayers.Format.OSM](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/OSM-js.html)

This page on the OSM Wiki has a wonderful example:[OpenLayers osm file example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_osm_file_example)

Comment: i already have that layer. now i need to add a feature to it, which comes after parsing the xml file. Something like "add elements one by one onto a vector layer"

Comment: If you need to convert from the XML to a feature, after you have added it as a layer, you'll have to do that through custom code. I don't think there is any function which will do that for you.